# Openlayers dateline crossing linestring disappears

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3, openlayers-5, angular-openlayers

I am working on openlayers, there is an issue when I try to add a linestring on the map which crosses the dateline several times.

To display the linestring across two worlds in the continuous segment I have added a function `HandleDateline()` which returns me modified *(shifted either to left or right world)* coordinates.

However, when you zoom-in on the left world to current settled view the linestring disappears. Also if you try to move the map to left, the line goes away.

The weird thing is if the line crosses more than 1 time, linestring on left worlds disappears otherwise same happens for right worlds. Too observe that, remove either first 3 or last 3 points from `datelinecrossing[]` which I will be posting down.

I am expecting a continuous linestring crossing the international dateline without any issues like disappearing.

If there is a better approach to this, I am open to all ideas.
Here is the bin : [`ol dateline problem`](https://jsbin.com/bawedax/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to split the lines crossing the dateline programmatically at the dateline.

```js
var points = [
  [-170, -10],
  [170, 0],
  [-170, 10]
];

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
vectorSource.addFeature(createFeature(points));

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      width: 2,
      color: "red"
    })
  })
});

var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [osmLayer, vectorLayer],
  target: document.getElementById("map"),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([180, 0], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"),
    zoom: 3
  })
});

var graticule = new ol.Graticule({
  strokeStyle: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: "rgba(255,120,0,0.9)",
    width: 1.5,
    lineDash: [0.5, 4]
  }),
  showLabels: true
});
graticule.setMap(map);

// -------------------------------------------------

function createFeature(points) {
  var pointsSplitted = [];
  var pointsArray = [];
  pointsSplitted.push(points[0]);
  var lastLambda = points[0][0];

  for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
    var lastPoint = points[i - 1];
    var nextPoint = points[i];
    if (Math.abs(nextPoint[0] - lastLambda) > 180) {
      var deltaX = xToValueRange(nextPoint[0] - lastPoint[0]);
      var deltaY = nextPoint[1] - lastPoint[1];
      var deltaXS = xToValueRange(180 - nextPoint[0]);
      var deltaYS;
      if (deltaX === 0) {
        deltaYS = 0;
      } else {
        deltaYS = deltaY / deltaX * deltaXS;
      }
      var sign = lastPoint[0] < 0 ? -1 : 1;
      pointsSplitted.push([180 * sign, nextPoint[1] + deltaYS]);
      pointsArray.push(pointsSplitted);
      pointsSplitted = [];
      pointsSplitted.push([-180 * sign, nextPoint[1] + deltaYS]);
    }
    pointsSplitted.push(nextPoint);
    lastLambda = nextPoint[0];
  }

  pointsArray.push(pointsSplitted);
  var geom = new ol.geom.MultiLineString(pointsArray);
  geom.transform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857");
  var feature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: geom
  });
  return feature;
}

function xToValueRange(x) {
  if (Math.abs(x) > 180) {
    var sign = x < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    return x - 2 * 180 * sign;
  } else {
    return x;
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="map" class="map" tabindex="0"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: How can I do that if line goes beyond anti-meridian and comes back several times?

Comment: Code snippet added.

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying `HandleDateline` so all coordinates are either in the western part of the normal world or the eastern part of the left world seems to fix it (so if the geometry crosses the date line the extent starts in the left world)

```
 function HandleDateline(array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length ; i++) {
            if (array[i][0] > 0) {
                array[i][0] -= 360;
            }
        }
    }
```

However in worlds to the right the points west of the dateline then appear to be rendered below to linestring, while those east of the dateline are above it.  Moving `HandleDateline(datelinecrossing);` above `datelinecrossing.forEach` fixes that.

You might also want to consider using a multipoint geometry for the points (unless you need them to be individually selectable).

```
HandleDateline(datelinecrossing);
var pdlcrossing = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.MultiPoint(datelinecrossing).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
});
drawingSource.addFeature(pdlcrossing);
var dlcrossing = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(datelinecrossing).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
});
drawingSource.addFeature(dlcrossing);
```

There is still a problem zooming in west of the dateline in the worlds on the right, so I think there will need to be two sets of each geometry, one offset to the left and another 360 degrees to the right:

```
function PlotGeometries(datelinecrossing){
  var pgeom = new ol.geom.MultiPoint(datelinecrossing);
  var pdlcrossing = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: pgeom.clone().transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
  });
  drawingSource.addFeature(pdlcrossing);
  pgeom.translate(360,0);
  var pdlcrossing2 = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: pgeom.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
  });
  drawingSource.addFeature(pdlcrossing2);
  var geom = new ol.geom.LineString(datelinecrossing);
  var dlcrossing = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: geom.clone().transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
  });
  drawingSource.addFeature(dlcrossing);
  geom.translate(360,0);
  var dlcrossing2 = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: geom.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
  });
  drawingSource.addFeature(dlcrossing2);
}
```

Comment: When you zoom-in on the right worlds, the line still goes away.
Here https://jsbin.com/bawedax/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I hadn't zoomed in far enough to notice it, but it looks like there has to be two sets of geometry to cover that.

Answer (score 0):

Just set an extent to the map view for the part of the world you're working on.

Comment: I am not working for particular part of the world, the line should be visible in every world. Perhaps a code snippet might help me understand what you are saying.

Comment: No, my suggestion would not be of help to you if you need the entire world. I just suggested that you set an extent to the view in the constructor, so the map view is limited to that extent.

https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.View.html

Comment: No we are not limiting worlds, appreciate your time.